# Read from a file and get the corresponding enum

Tags: python, file, enums

Hi I need to use a script to make some pictures. I have an enum with the corresponding path of image.

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    Arsenal = 'Club Logos/English-Football-Clubs/1. Premier League/Arsenal FC.ico'
```

and I have a text where I have a line with the word 'Arsenal' and I want to read the line and depending on the string use the path

Something like this

```py
with open('team_in.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(MyEnum.line_TRASFORMED_IN_ENUM.value) # print the path where line=='Arsenal'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Remember that when you're reading from a file there's the \n character at the end of the string. So you need to delete it using

```
line=line.strip()
```

so finally

```
print(MyEnum[line].value)
```